# bing map does not load

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, bing-maps

Im doing a web application in C# and ASP.NET MVC4.
Im having a problem with loading a map on one of my view pages...
I have the map on my Details page and the you go from Index page to Details page.

This is some of my code:

```
<div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="createWalkingRoute" onclick="createDirections();" />
</div>
<div id='directionsItinerary'> </div>


 @section scripts{

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;
      var directionsManager;
      var directionsErrorEventObj;
      var directionsUpdatedEventObj;

      function getMap() {
          map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), { credentials: 'mykey' });
      }

      function createDirectionsManager() {
          var displayMessage;
          if (!directionsManager) {
              directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
              displayMessage = 'Directions Module loaded\n';
              displayMessage += 'Directions Manager loaded';
          }
          alert(displayMessage);
          directionsManager.resetDirections();
          directionsErrorEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', function (arg) { alert(arg.message) });
          directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function () { alert('Directions updated') });
      }

      function createWalkingRoute() {
          if (!directionsManager) { createDirectionsManager(); }
          directionsManager.resetDirections();
          // Set Route Mode to walking 
          directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.walking });
          var seattleWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Seattle, WA' });
          directionsManager.addWaypoint(seattleWaypoint);
          var redmondWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Redmond, WA', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.678561, -122.130993) });
          directionsManager.addWaypoint(redmondWaypoint);
          // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
          directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsItinerary') });
          alert('Calculating directions...');
          directionsManager.calculateDirections();
      }

      function createDirections() {
          if (!directionsManager) {
              Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', { callback: createWalkingRoute });
          }
          else {
              createWalkingRoute();
          }
      }

getMap();

  </script>

 }
```

When you go first go on the Details page the map doesn't load. However if the page is then refreshed, then the map loads after. So to me this is some sort of loading problem. But after trying for few hours Im absolutely stuck.
Can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

put the `getMap()` call into some place where it will be called after the page is loaded, for example the [body onload event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp).  If you are using jquery, [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Bojin Li: thanks for this, I have tried both of these but the map still wont load until page is refreshed.

Comment: Your solution is the one explained by Bojin Li, in fact, you should refer to the iSDK here: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7
Your code is executed before the Bing Maps scripts (added from the script reference) has been loaded into the page (in the browser)